# Subtracting features from one layer using another layer in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlay, intersect, parcel, erase

I have 2 layers of land parcels for a particular area (shown on top of each other like so):

[image]

The darker parcel lines and road polygons are from an earlier parcel map. The land has been developed and many more small land parcels have been added. I want to create a layer that shows all of the new land parcels (i.e. the small parcels that are lightly highlighted) only.

Is there a certain tool in ArcGIS Desktop that I can use to create a layer that has only the new parcels in it (the lightly shaded boxes)?

I have tried performing different types of clipping and intersection operations but I have not been able to generate what I'm looking for.

Comment: By asking how to do something and then tagging two products that could probably do it you are effectively asking two questions which makes this too broad.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to focus your question on one or other.  I recommend asking about the one you are most likely to use.  You can always ask about the other one in a separate question.  As much as possible try to describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: You say that you have "tried performing different types of clipping and intersection operations" but in detail what have you tried i.e. all tools and parameter values.  It sounds like you may be looking for Erase.